# If two Crystal Masters use fusion do their embedded gems stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

If two characters who both have levels in the [*Crystal Master*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20040625d) prestige class use [*fusion*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fusion.htm), does the resulting gestalt retain all of the embedded gems of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, though if both creatures have chosen the same gem, they only gain its benefit once.

From the [*fusion* description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fusion.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Likewise, all feats, racial abilities, and **class features** are pooled (if both creatures have the **same ability**, the fused being gains it only once).

From the [Crystal Master class description](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20040625d) (emphasis mine):

> **Embedded Gems**
>
> The following gems provide **different abilities** or enhancements to the crystal master. Each type of gem can be embedded only once.

Since the abilities from embedded gems are class features, they're pooled between the fused creatures.  Since different gems provide different abilities, they don't trigger the "same ability" exception.